# AutoClose for ngbDropdown using keyboard navigation

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngbDropdown with auto close. Using non-keyboard navigation dropdown menus are correctly dismissed as I click on different dropdown buttons. Using the keyboard I can tab and press enter and the dropdown menu appears. When I tab to a different dropdown and press enter, the previous menu is not dismissed resulting in 2 visible dropdown menus. It auto close not supported for keyboard navigation? Here is a small example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xg5veq-zbtuys

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We developed a workaround that closes the dropdown when navigating off of it with the keyboard.

This workaround required generating a uid for each component.

```
...
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

@Component({
selector: "app-flyout-component",
templateUrl: "./flyout-component.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./flyout-component.component.css"],
providers: [NgbDropdownConfig]
})
export class FlyoutComponentComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild("drop", { static: false }) drop: any;
initDone = false;
uid: string;

constructor(ngbDropdownConfig: NgbDropdownConfig) {
this.uid = this.$generateUUID();
}
```

The uid is used to identify which ngbDropdownToggle button was clicked. In the click handler we set the focus to the first item in the dropdown.

The workaround also has a focuslost event handler that closes the dropdown when tabbing off.

The code is in the original stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xg5veq-zbtuys